# Align div with first vertically center div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vertical-alignment

I have a page, where I'm showing images side by side according to the category they belong to, each image array begins with the category it belongs to. Images vary in their width & height, but are put into a div with an absolute height of 330px.

**CSS:**

```
.front-index {  
margin: 0 1em 0 2em; 
}

.front-work { 
    margin: 0 2em 2em 0; 
    display: table; 
    width: 66px; 
    position: relative;
    height: 330px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

.front-work img { 
    margin: .3em 0 .3em 0; 
}

.wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wraptocenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.front-index,
.front-work {
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="front-index"><p>How to get<br /> this text on the same line with<br /> yellow image on the right?</p></div>


    <div class="front-work">
        <div class="wraptocenter">
            <img width="162" height="250" src="http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Yellow-Wallpaper-yellow-646738_800_600.jpg"/>
        </div>  
    </div>  

    <div class="front-work">
        <div class="wraptocenter">
            <img width="250" height="166" src="http://www.takenseriouslyamusing.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Blue.png"/>
        </div>  
    </div>
…
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rCAKa/9/

I'd like to align the text to the same line as the first image on the right.

What I had in mind, is that may-be this should be done in jquery. Ie. somehow measure the  image distance from the top inside the .front-work div and then assign the value to the .front-index div as an inline code (top: whatever px ).

Maybe someone of you have faced this kind of problem and know a solution to this kind of problem? CSS or JS.

Comment: where is the yellow image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion I don't think that what you're doing is possible through CSS - it requires some simple JavaScript trickery because you have to know the relative position (from the top of the container) of the first image on the right in order to position the text - something which CSS isn't quite designed for.

The strategy in JS would be:

1. Loop through each element with text that you want to position
2. Fetch the vertical top offset of the first image to the right (relative to containing parent)
3. Set top padding matching to top position of image. Alternatively, you can set the top position, paddings or margins of the child elements, or other ways to reposition the text.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".front-index").each(function() {
           var fromTop = $(this).next().find("img").position().top;
           $(this).css({
               "padding-top":fromTop
           });
       });
   });
   ```

I have forked your fiddle, and you can see it in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/LT54V/1/

p/s: On a related note, `.wraptocenter * { }` is probably not the best (as in, most efficient) selector out there, because if you have many child elements in the element (who may or may have even more child elements), CSS will have to iterate through all of them. Instead, try using `.wraptocenter > * { }` or just `.wraptocenter img { }` :)

Comment: JEAH! This is the thing I was after. I thought that this is a jquery solution, but my knowlege about it is bad. Thanks for the CSS tip also. Kudos!

Comment: I realized that you have set a 0.3em top and bottom margin for the images, and that's why the text don't quite line up. You can either add the marginTop value to the fromTop variable in jQuery, or make do without the image margins :)

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to solve the problem using css. After a while I figured out the following logics:

1. Create a div with the same height as the cell on the right with the display set as table
2. Make a table-cell div in the first one that centers vertically
3. In this div make another subdiv with the same height as the image.

The HTML code is then this:

```
<div class="front-index">
    <div class="front-index-inner">
        <div style="height:250px;">
            <p>How to get<br /> this text on the same line with<br /> yellow image on the right?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and as my CSS part this:

```
.front-index {  
    margin: 0 1em 0 2em; 
    display: table;
    height: 330px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.front-index-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can see the result over here: http://jsfiddle.net/rCAKa/10/

I hope this brings a solution to you that is clear, understandable and useful.

Greetings,

Jef

Comment: Helo Jef. Thank you for your answer and it works for the first one. But I was after a solution, that would work for both texts, so teddyrised answer is the right one

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rCAKa/11/ Edited it for the second text aswell, used exactly the same working method.